# `If` statement doesn't work

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I wrote an if statement but I don't know why it doesn't work.

First "if statement" checks if user wanted write a test in English (`uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu ==  'EN'`). It should display only questions in English (`pytanie.title`). If computer doesn't find user who wanted write a test in English should check other possibilities (`f.e uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu ==  'DE'`) and display questions in other languages.

I get questions only in English: (It seems everything is ok. On the bottom of the page every user has a description (DE or EN or FR) which language has chosen.

[You can check this file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYgvFjXrSEfU3VrTkhGbkN5aVE/view?usp=sharing)

```
def test_qr(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="egzamin.pdf"'

    uzyt = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user_id')
    pytanie = Pytanie.objects.all().order_by('published')
    pytanieDE = PytanieDE.objects.all().order_by('published')
    pytanieFR = PytanieFR.objects.all().order_by('published')

    p = canvas.Canvas(response)

    for z, uzyt in enumerate(UserProfile.objects.all()):

        if uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu ==  'EN' :

            for i, pytanie in enumerate(Pytanie.objects.all()):
                p.drawString(10, 400 + i*210, ' '+ pytanie.title)
        elif uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu ==  'DE' :
            for i, pytanieDE in enumerate(Pytanie.objects.all()):
                p.drawString(10, 400 + i*210, ' '+ pytanieDE.title)
        elif uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu ==  'FR' :
            for i, pytanieFR in enumerate(Pytanie.objects.all()):
                p.drawString(10, 400 + i*210, ' '+ pytanieFR.title)        


        qrw = QrCodeWidget('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/userprofile/userprofile/'+str(uzyt.user_id)+'/') 
        b = qrw.getBounds()

        w=b[2]-b[0] 
        h=b[3]-b[1] 

        d = Drawing(100, 100, transform=[100./w, 0, 0, 100./h, 0, 0]) 
        d.add(qrw)

        renderPDF.draw(d, p, 1, 1+z*10)
        p.drawString(100, 1 + z*10, ' '+ str(uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu)+ ' ' + str(uzyt.imie) + ' ' + str(uzyt.nazwisko) + ' '+ str(uzyt.kierunek) ) 
        p.showPage()



    p.save()
    return response
```

Comment: Could you add the error you got ?

Answer (score 2):

All your loops like

```
for i, pytanieDE in enumerate(Pytanie.objects.all()):
```

are absolutely identical except for the irrelevant spelling of the loop variable -- in each and every case, you're using **all** `Pytanie` objects, not being at all selective about them.

So the `if/elif` may work perfectly but you'll never know since you do exactly the same thing on each stanza of that decision tree!-)

Your loop variable names clash with the previous assignments:

```
pytanie = Pytanie.objects.all().order_by('published')
pytanieDE = PytanieDE.objects.all().order_by('published')
pytanieFR = PytanieFR.objects.all().order_by('published')
```

and thus override them (and repeat the `.objects.all()` query).

I imagine what you actually **wanted** to do, as opposed to what you actually show above, might be something like:

```
    if uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu == 'EN':
        for i, pyt in enumerate(pytanie):
            p.drawString(10, 400 + i*210, ' '+ pyt.title)
    elif uzyt.jezyk_egzaminu == 'DE':
        for i, pytDE in enumerate(pytanieDE):
            p.drawString(10, 400 + i*210, ' '+ pytDE.title)
```

and so on -- enumerating the queries you've already prepared, and with loop variables named **differently** from the queries to avoid wiping them out!-)

Comment: Of course. It was so easy :) I get where is a problem :) Thank you :)